# Не могу подключить Realm в Android studio (kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, realm

Не могу подключить Realm, делаю всё по официальной документации. Вот часть моего gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:7.0.0-beta"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}
и ещё

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

}

Ошибка такая:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyKotlin2'.
```

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:7.0.0-beta.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/7.0.0-beta/realm-gradle-plugin-7.0.0-beta.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/7.0.0-beta/realm-gradle-plugin-7.0.0-beta.pom
> Required by:
> project :

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Comment: Наверное устаревшую бэта версию уже потёрли с репозитория. Попробуйте свежую: `10.0.1`

Comment: Пробовал. 10.0.1 - это версия для Java, для kotlin версия 7 beta. Но в любом случае не получается, не знаю, куда копать

Comment: Создал новый проект, тоже не помогло. RxJava, например, подключается нормально

Comment: Откуда вы берёте информацию о том, что для котлина нужна определённая версия? Я много лет назад использовал Realm и он работал без проблем и для Java и для Kotlin. Отдельных сборок под язык не было. У меня складывается впечатление, что вы используете устаревшую документацию и/или устаревшие и даже неправильные статьи.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ваш комментарий действительно мне помог. Я использовал устаревшую документацию, о чём красным шрифтом было написано на сайте, всему виной мой плохой английский, не так трактовал эти надписи. Версия уже 10.2.0. И еще моей ошибкой было прописывать плагины id 'kotlin-kapt' и
    id 'realm-android' сразу, потом синхронизировать gradle. Это нужно было делать всё пошагово. Сначала прописать dependencies -> синхронизировать, потом плагины и еще добавить realm {
        syncEnabled = true
    } и еще раз synchronize

Comment: Рад был помочь) Ваш комментарий можно прямо в ответ скопировать - возможно кому-то ещё пригодится. Ну и плюсов можно получить - больше возможностей сайта откроется)

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал устаревшую документацию, о чём красным шрифтом было написано на сайте, всему виной мой плохой английский, не так трактовал эти надписи. Версия уже 10.2.0. И еще моей ошибкой было прописывать плагины id 'kotlin-kapt' и id 'realm-android' сразу, вместе с dependencies, потом один раз синхронизировать gradle. Это нужно было делать всё пошагово, по очереди. Сначала прописать dependencies -> синхронизировать, потом плагины и еще добавить realm { syncEnabled = true } и еще раз synchronize.